# Join tables and display the data in Magento Grid using XML

Tags: magento

I am trying to customise Magento Sales/Order/Grid by adding columns to display data for

Customer_Id
Billing_Address
Shipping_Address

I've created a module following an earlier post

I am now trying to join the tables but haven't been able to figure out how to do this using XML.

```
<gridcontrol>
    <grids>
        <sales_order_grid>
            <!-- remove order id -->
            <shipping_address>
                <add>
                    <header>Shipping Address</header>
                    <!-- join shipping address from sales/order table -->
                    <join table="sales_flat_order_address" condition="sales_flat_order_address.entity_id={{table}}.street" field="street"/>
                </add>
                <after>status</after>
            </shipping_address>
            <billing_address>
                <add>
                    <header>Billing Address</header>
                    <!-- join shipping address from sales/order table -->
                    <join table="sales_flat_order_address" condition="sales_flat_order_address.entity_id={{table}}.street" field="street"/>
                </add>
                <after>status</after>
            </billing_address>
            <customer_id>
                <add>
                    <header>Customer Id</header>
                    <!-- join shipping address from sales/order table -->
                    <join table="sales_flat_order" condition="main_table.cutomer_id={{table}}.customer_id" field="customer_id"/>
                </add>
                <after>status</after>
            </customer_id>            
        </sales_order_grid>
    </grids>
</gridcontrol>
```

I have the new columns showing in my grid but there are empty so I know I am doing something incorrectly and I assume it is something really simple. I would be grateful if someone could show me how to join the correct tables using this method.

Comment: I know you are trying to get a hard job done. Why don't you use an extension. please check out http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/enhanced-admin-grids-editor.html

Comment: @SAM I had used this extension but it doesn't allow me to add columns to the Sales/Order_Grid. Everywhere else is fine including the Manage products grid but the extension is still in Alpha so some functionality has yet to be added.

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you try doing , _prepareCollection()

```
$collection->getSelect()->columns(array('filename' => new Zend_Db_Expr ("(SELECT 
filename FROM table_name WHERE customer_id =e.entity_id)")));
        $this->setCollection($collection);
```